# Maven error : InvocationTargetException: Tomcat connector in failed state fiware-cepheus

Tags: maven, tomcat, fiware

While I want to run this command  **spring-boot:run** 
i get that error

```
 Failed to execute goal org .springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven plugin:1.2.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project cepheus-cep: Anexception    occured while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Tomcat connector in failed state -
```

I  change the Tomcat port and restart it and i still have the same problem 
what should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Tomcat cannot use the default port, it must be already used by another application.

You can start a Spring Boot application with a custom port from command line with the `--server.port` option.

```
java -jar myapp.jar --server.port=8181
```

or from source directly with:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="--server.port=8181"
```

Comment: i try the second one mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="--server.port=8181"  and it run correctly but no logs appear on it  when i use this comand " killall -9 java" and  then mvn  spring-boot:run its run and the logs of example 1 appear but it case different problem  when i want to send any thing out side my machine to 8080 i got connection refused

Comment: my question now to be more specific how i install cephues-cep using Debian package and didn't case problem when run this command mvn spring-boot:run

Answer (score 3):

The problem  was there was another Cepheus already running on the same port so I solved it by using this command:

```
killall -9 java
```

and rerun the command

```
mvn spring-boot run
```

and it works fine.